# jQuery fadeOut/fadeIn not working as expected?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to show one `fieldset` at a time, based on the user's selection. The theory is that, all fieldsets should hide first, then the selected fieldset should be shown. I'm using jQuery's `fadeOut` and 'fadeIn` functions.

You can see a fiddle of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/DtaHQ/1/).

But it doesn't work just fine. What's wrong? When you change the **ownership type**, first two fieldsets are shown, then they dim and fade out, and then the intended fieldset appears. However, the desired behavior is that, on change of the **ownership type**, the currently visible fieldset simply fade out, and then the intended fieldset fade in.

Comment: You should post the code here for future use in case jsfiddle doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use a 'promise' http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ to be sure that fadein happens after when fieldset has faded out.

```
$(function() {
    var ownershipType = $('#ownershipType').first();
    var fieldsets = $('fieldset');
    ownershipType.change(function() {
        var promise = fieldsets.fadeOut(2000);
        $.when(promise).then( function () {$('fieldset[data-ownership-type=' + ownershipType.val() + ']').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DtaHQ/26/

Comment: Well, well! I learned just something new. Thanks for your genus way @Vertigo.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you already have hidden `fieldset` and for these elements animation of the `fadeOut` fires immediately, because of it's already hidden.

Try to change to this:

```
$(function() {
    var ownershipType = $('#ownershipType').first();
    ownershipType.change(function() {
        $('fieldset:visible').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $('fieldset[data-ownership-type=' + ownershipType.val() + ']').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/DtaHQ/20/

Comment: Your explanation just rocked @Samich. Great note. Thanks and +1

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to

```
$(function() {
    var ownershipType = $('#ownershipType').first();
    var fieldsets = $('fieldset');
    ownershipType.change(function() {
        $('fieldset:visible').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $('fieldset[data-ownership-type=' + ownershipType.val() + ']').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

You only want to fade out the fieldset that is currently visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/DtaHQ/24/

Comment: But why my code doesn't work? I mean, after all, fading out something that is invisible shouldn't break anything?

Comment: Samich has an answer.  Your original code did say "fade out ALL fieldsets."  But you have a good point.  [The documentation for fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) does say that already hidden divs are not subject to this animation. :)  Helps to explain the nice number of upvotes to your question!